# Automated bulk screencaps of video

Tags: video, automation

Can anyone suggest a program for creating a screencap for each of a large number of video files?

Comment: What are you trying to do exactly?

Comment: Isn't it clear? He wants to take a 'screenshot' of a series of videos automatically, using some sort to batch script or something

Answer (score 2):

[VideoContactSheet](http://nod5.dcmembers.com/videocontactsheet.html) should do what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

You might get some more help at [VideoHelp.com](http://www.videohelp.com/).  [Here's a google search](http://www.google.com/search?q=create+video+thumbnails&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t&rls=org.mozilla:en-US:official&client=firefox-a) of what I think you're looking for.

Answer (score -1):

It's unclear exactly what you are trying to do.  If you are simply trying to batch process video files you can use something like [VLC media player](http://www.videolan.org/) to perform batch conversions.